# automatic reloading of jupyter notebook after crash

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

is there a way to reload automatically a jupyter notebook, each time it crashes ?

I am actually running a notebook, that trains a Deep learning model (the notebook can reload the last state of model, with state of optimizer and scheduler, after each restart of the kernel ), so that reloading the notebook after a crash enables to get back the last state without a substantial loss of computations.

I was wondering if there was a simple way to do that using the jupyter notebook API, or a signal from the jupyter notebook for example (maybe on logs).

Also, I am running the notebook on google cloud platform (on compute engine), if you know any efficient way to do it, using the GCP troubleshooting services, and the logging agent, it might be interested for me and for others with the same issue.

Thank you again for you time.

I tried to look up for a solution on stack overflow, but I didn't find any similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

"reloading the notebook after a crash enables to get back the last state without a substantial loss of computations."

What do you call a crash?, does it generate logs that can be parsed from `/var/log` or other location (e.g `journalctl -u jupyter.service`) ? If so you can manually create a shell script.

With User Managed Notebooks you have the concept of `post-startup-script` or `startup-script`

`post-startup-script`, is path to a Bash script that automatically runs after a notebook instance fully boots up. The path must be a URL or Cloud Storage path. Example: "gs://path-to-file/file-name"

This script can be a loop that monitors the crash you mention

Comment: It's not a crash at the level of the code ,the notebook, sometimes randomnly stop running , after certain time. I am looking for a solution, that would restart the kernel, and rerun all the cell automatically, without having to periodically check if the notebook must be restarted.
Your solution seems interesting, but I am not aware of a signal that is sent when the notebook stops running.

Comment: "the notebook, sometimes randomnly stop running , after certain time" can you be more specific, VM stops? UI is inaccessible? Cell stop running? Jupyter service stops?

Comment: no, the VM doesn't stop, the VM keeps running, but the jupyter service stops running (the jupyter notebook appears as it is still running and same for the cell ). I think, it's the UI that is not accessible, but even if I reload the page or I copy/paster the same url, I can't get back to the last state of the jupyter' run. The simplest solution I found, was to make checkpoint for the state of notebook in order to minimize the loss. So, to resume I am not sure , if it is at the level of the UI, or beyong the UI, as the access to it seems lost.

Comment: "the jupyter service stops running", so you have confirmed this with 'systemctl status jupyter.service'? or how? if Jupyter service stops, my original suggestion is still true with the script that take some action. Have you actually root cause why the Jupyter service starts? What model? For how long it runs? etc. Please add more details since question is very vague.

Comment: by "the jupyter service stops running", I mean that the notebook stops 
outputing logs, writting on files, and the UI is inaccessible, 
(stopping the notebook, and rerunning the cells doesn't have any effect), 
the only available possibility is to restart the kernel. 
Unfortunately, the error is hard to reproduce but happens randomly
 several times a day , and doesn't seem to be correlated with ram and cpu 
usage. 
I'll try to use your method, then give feed-back about your solution here,
as soon, as I'll have time to test it.
Thanks again :)

Comment: You have 2 dependencies here: 1) Jupyter service status and 2) your access to the Jupyter UI. If you are accessing via Vertex Notebooks, authentication has a 24 hr cookie. For how long your jobs run? What ML framework? Can you describe the scenario. What machine type? Can you describe simple steps to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**I think you need to add following the code before executing**

```
import os
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"
```

[image: .]